# Encode binary data into ASCII while preserving most of its valid characters

Tags: encoding, escaping, ascii

When displaying a `bytes` object in python the print function will display a select number values as ASCII characters instead of their numeric representation.

```
>>> b"1 2 \x30 a b \x80"
b'1 2 0 a b \x80'
```

Is there a known encoding that would allow a set of binary data containing mostly ASCII text to be put into a valid ASCII string where the few invalid characters are replaced by a numeric representation, similarly to what python does with `bytes`?

Edit:
I used python's `bytes.repr` as an example of what the encoding would do, the project we need this for is written in c++, something like a "language agnostic" spec would be nice.

Edit 2:
Think of this as a base64 alternative so that binary data that is mostly ASCII does not get altered too much.

Comment: You mean it automatically detects what is ASCII in binary data and what is numerical right?

Comment: @MarkMeyer This specifically is for c++, I just used python as an example, I don't remember placing the python tag on the post.

Comment: @Facundo if it's specifically for c++ why are you using python in your example and explicitly saying you have a python bytes object. :confused:.

Comment: I added the Python tag because the shown example was in Python, and nowhere did you mention anything about C++, or about being language-agnostic. If it's for a C++ program then you should mention that inside the question itself, add the C++ tag, and show a [mcve] of your attempt together with a description about the problems you have with it. Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And it's really not an encoding-issue, and not possible to implement in a language-agnostic way (any kind of implementation would by definition not be language-agnostic).

Comment: I don't see why I would need to mention any language, the question is about encodings. I mentioned python's bytes object because it is the only thing I've seen that does this.

Comment: As for how to implement it in C++, just iterate over the binary blob byte by byte. If [it is printable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isprint) add it to an output string stream, otherwise add it to the stream as an integer in hexadecimal form.

Comment: If you want a language-agnostic answer, it can only be this: It's not possible, because it's not an encoding issue. It can only be done using actual code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How is this "Not really an encoding-issue"? It's written on the title. I did not ask for a library or an implementation, that would definitely not be language-agnostic.

Comment: There's no standard for "binary data", what the "binary data" is depends on your interpretation of it. You state that you want a string-representation of that data, where some parts of it is interpreted as ASCII characters, and other parts should be represented by the hexadecimal value of the bytes. It's simply how your program interprets that data, and it can only be done in an implementation as actual code. That you say "I want it to be an encoding issue" doesn't necessarily make it so.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The idea is to transform invalid ASCII characters into some intermediate form so that it can be sent via mediums that only accept ASCII text. I don't understand how that is much different from the idea of base64 encoding. It does not matter what representation we give to the binary data.

Comment: Now I see what you men with the term "encoding". It is however the wrong term, the correct term is *representation*. ASCII or UTF-8 is an *encoding*, base64 is a *representation*. There are some "standard" ways to *represent* binary data in printable form, you mention base64 which is indeed one of them. And there are pseudo-code and descriptive algorithms available for these "standard" ways. The way you want to represent the data is well-known and the algorithm for it I have already mentioned (with some implementation-specific bits). Generalize that and you have your language-agnostic answer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude RFC3548 calls baseXX "Data Encodings" including wikipedia and many others, I don't believe I used the wrong term.